# How to have a large java or python datastructure remain persistent in memory so that other programs can "query" it (like a database)?

Tags: java, python, multithreading, graph

I have a graph structure with a few thousand nodes that I want to make a part of a web application.  I've spent dozens of hours trying and reading up Neo4j and Cypher, and it's looking like they don't currently offer certain shortestpath-like traversals that I need.

With my graph datastructure, loading it into memory takes 10-50 times as long as a typical query

So it'd only be feasible if every user could interact with a single instance of a python program instead of each spawning their own instance of it.  It needs to sit there and listen for requests of some kind.

I'd prefer to do this in python since I'm using a python web framework, but java is fine too, especially if it'd be faster.

Is this a reasonable alternative to using a database like Neo4j (given its lack of a particular feature), and if so, what do I need to look into to figure out how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to consider an in-memory key-value store like ramcloud, which at least historically had Python bindings: https://ramcloud.stanford.edu/wiki/display/ramcloud/Python+Bindings

Comment: Maybe ask at https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!forum/arangodb am pretty sure it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a server-client-architecture, using some protocol, e.g. [json-rpc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-jsonrpc/0.3.4). But you have to consider, that you're missing important features like transactions, reliability.
Alternatively, as Neo4j is open source, you could add your shortestpath-like traversals to the code. Third way is to look at other graph databases, perhaps these provide the functions you need. (ArangoDB, OrientDB, ...)